# Animation not showing in custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, view

I have created a custom layout to go in a listview. I have an animation in the custom layout, but I cannot get it to show. The animation works if I take it out of the custom listview, but then it obviously isn't in the listview!

The code snippets below show exactly what I am calling. I believe the error lies with the way I am using the LayoutInflator, but I am not sure what is going on.

Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        ArrayAdapter<Group> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Group>(this, custom_listview_activetethers, R.id.label, currentUser.getGroupList());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tether_list);

        //standard animated image in the layout, works fine but obviously not in the listview
        ImageView mImageViewEmptying = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tetherPulseAnimationTest);
        ((AnimationDrawable) mImageViewEmptying.getBackground()).start();

        //custom animated image, does not show
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_activetethers, null);

        ImageView mImageViewFilling = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tetherPulseAnimation);
        ((AnimationDrawable) mImageViewFilling.getBackground()).start();
```

Layout (containing a working example of the animation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_tether_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="uk.tether.topcom.tether.TetherListActivity">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tetherPulseAnimationTest"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:background="@drawable/tetheredanimation"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom layout (Only thing that doesn't show is the animation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilepic"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/tetherlogo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tetherPulseAnimation"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:background="@drawable/tetheredanimation"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to get this to work, but still no luck! I thought inflating and retrieving the view, then calling the animation from that view would work, but it hasn't.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong, because i'm feeling quite lost!

Edit:
Example of what it looks like, showing working elements of custom layout and where the animations should be in red. Also shows the non-custom animation working in the top left to rule out an issue with images etc.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using hard coded layout_width values, I would venture to say that you ImageView that contains the animation is pushed off the screen. (Can turn on layout boundaries in Developer options on the device to check, but this is besides the point).

You should really not be hard coding such values, and lay out views relative to each other or with weights. As a simple fix, try setting the layout_width of the TextView to 0dp and the weight to 1. This means it will occupy the rest of the available space in the layout.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am not too great on the front end side of things so I just wanted some test code that worked. But your suggestion worked, and I can see the blue dots, just they are still (no animation).

Comment: So sadly there is still an issue with the inflation and starting of the animation.